# step definition regex wtih cucumber-protractor framework

Tags: protractor, cucumber

Is there any way in that framework to use a regex for including steps that are similar.
Example:
the user logs in
a user logs in
the user can log in

In java, I used to be able to do:

Given(^(?:the|a) use (?:can log|logs) in$)

And this would recognize all the 3 steps above. It seems like the protractor-cucumber framework doesn't recognize those regex. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I was using quotes around the step definition like:
When("the user enters correct credentials", async() {
and that doesn't support regex.

Changed it to
When(/^the user enters (correct|incorrect) credentials$/, async(word)=> {

And now I can use regex in the middle as I was hoping to.